# How to request an "add import" intention to place it in the current function?

Tags: pycharm

As shown in the screenshot, the "add import" intention is being activated. It does work but puts the import way at top of file. Even the "locally" goes somewhere else - I have to hunt it down.  Is there any way to import it right there in the current function method?

[image]